# Jolokia - Get many attributes in a single request

Tags: java, jmx, jolokia

I'd like to perform a single call to Jolokia and get all the values of the attributes for the JVM Pools.

This works fine for a single attribute:

```
http://myserver/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code%20Cache/Name/
```

But if i'd like to get the "Usage" attribute with it, I should be able to provide a comma separated list (according to the chapter 6.2.1.1 of [Jolokia documentation](http://www.jolokia.org/reference/html/protocol.html):

```
http://myserver/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=Code%20Cache/Name,Usage/
```

But what I get is:  "javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException: No such attribute: Name,Usage

I've tried to escape it in different ways, without success....

Comment: What version of Jolokia do you use ? (simply call `http://myserver/jolokia` to get the version information)

Comment: @RolandHuß Here it is! Thanks {"timestamp":1405453600,"status":200,"request":{"type":"version"},"value":{"protocol":"5.0","agent":"0.95","info":{"product":"tomcat","vendor":"Apache","version":"7.0.47"}}}

Comment: Your agent is far to old and does not support multiple attribute read. This is available since 1.0.0. See also http://www.jolokia.org/changes-report.html. Please update (current version: 1.2.2)